# Prey ending question (HEAVY SPOILERS)

Tags: prey

I wish I could ask about what Prey's ending means in general, but it might be considered too broad.

So my question is about operators. Why at the end only Alex is a human? Why other characters are presented as operators? Was they real or their characters was created only for simulation and they are AI? If not, where are original characters at the end? Are they dead?

And what happened to canon, original Alex Yu? Did he return to Earth resulting in infection?

Comment: Game lacks information to clarify, what happened to other people, who were presented as operators, but Alex seems to be real one, implying that real Morgan chose to use null-wave emitter instead of station self-destruction.

Comment: Rolling back spoilers, as questions have to make sense without spoilers.  Since the whole question was spoiled, that doesn't meet that requirement.